# empty string return resource id in php

Tags: php, sql

i have this php:

```
$description = mysql_query(utf8_decode("SELECT `typealertesecmar` FROM `Opérations n°" . $row['idops'] . "` WHERE `typealertesecmar`!='' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1")) or die(mysql_error());
    $row6 = array();

    while($row7 = mysql_fetch_assoc($description)) {
        $row6[] = $row7;
    }
    foreach($row6 as $row7) { 
        $description = utf8_encode(stripslashes($row7['typealertesecmar']));
    }
```

this code return to me the last 'typealertesecmar' who is not empty.
this code is repeated for several other fields

after i try to do this

```
if (empty($description) && empty($complement) && empty($nbperso) && empty($infrapec) && empty($rempec) && empty($remrsm)) {
    echo "<td>Aucune Information sur l'opération n'est disponible.</td>";
  }
  elseif (empty($description) && empty($complement) && empty($nbperso) && empty($infrapec) && empty($rempec)) {
    echo"<td>Description RSM : " . $remrsm . "</td>";
  }
```

etc.. for all field i try to verify if field is empty to echo a string.
but return multiple 'Resource id #' for empty field

help please!

Comment: if your query returned no results then the final value of `$description` will be `Resource id#`. please be sensible when naming your variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_query()` does not directly return data, it returns a resource identifier which you can use to grab rows from the result set.

Suggest changing to:

```
$description = ''; // default blank value
$result = mysql_query(utf8_decode("SELECT `typealertesecmar` FROM `Opérations n°" . $row['idops'] . "` WHERE `typealertesecmar`!='' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1")) or die(mysql_error());
$row6 = array();

if($result && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row7 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $row6[] = $row7;
    }
}
```

Now, `$description` will be an empty string and `$row6` will be an empty array, if no results were found in the query.

---

Side note: the `mysql_*` library has long been deprecated, consider upgrading to PDO or MySQLi. You have a parameter in your query so there may be a [Second Order SQL Injection](http://www.esecforte.com/blog/second-order-sql-injection/) vulnerability there. This query would be a good candidate for a Prepared Statement in PDO or MySQLi.